# Advanced trigonometrics with Escalene Triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[image: Escalene Triangle]

I have this triangle in which $a = \frac{ \pi }{2} d+ R$. I know the values of $c$ and $R$ and I want to **solve for d**. Is it possible? I have tried calculating angles with the law of cosines and than using the sum of the angles equals $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but I got stuck with some arcos functions, Am I missing something?

Comment: Whats the meaning of $R$?

Comment: It is a constant in my problem. Sorry, should be clearer.

Comment: Are you sure you don’t have anything else? I believe this info doesn’t uniquely identify a triangle.

Comment: To solve a traingle you need 3 data (3 angles is not enough). You have only a data $c$ and a relation between the other 2 sides. You may find infinite $a,d$ pairs.

Comment: I doubt $R$ is just any constant. It is probably radius of the circumcircle of the given triangle . Otherwise $R$ is a strange notation for a constant.